# TextViews not saving values when changing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with a number of fragments. In all fragments, I get the views in `onViewCreated`, like this:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
}
```

I'm not storing the textview's text in the state. One fragment extends `ListFragment` and I change the adapter's items and refresh the listview.

When I go back to previous fragments (I use `popBackStack()` because I need to use a Back button (app runs in kiosk mode), text in some fragments is lost while in others (and the listview) the changes done stay there.

I'm using `replace` to replace the current fragment in the frame.

**EDIT**

The values that are being lost are of TextViews and ImageButtons (image resource). The text in EditText views are not lost.

Why is this happening in just some fragments and how can I solve this data loss?

Comment: Are you using replace or add in your transactions?

Comment: @PedroOliveira I'm using replace.

Answer (score 8):

You have to use

```
android:freezesText="true"
```

In your layout textviews whose text you want to be preserved.

I hope it helps.

Comment: You saved my day!!

Comment: I'm glad to know my answer helped you, @marcosE. By learning that I helped you, I got that great feeling of giving back to the community a little bit of the huge knowledge that I got from it! Thanks for letting me know. :)

Comment: Perfect solution! I was looking for this one at least an hour. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand your situation:

- You are showing an instance of `Fragment1` which contains your `TextView`.
- You replace your instance of `Fragment1` on the screen with an instance of `Fragment2`.
- You return to `Fragment1`, but when you do, the text in the `TextView` has been lost.

I have seen situations where this occurs because the instance of `Fragment1` that contained the original `TextView` is not the same instance of `Fragment1` that is shown the second time. If you are showing two different instances of `Fragment1`, the second instance will not display the text that the first instance contained in its own text view.

So take a look at the code that is managing your fragment transactions. Are you creating new instances of your fragments before showing them? If so, you'll have to keep references to the fragments that you want to retain instead of recreating them every time.

Another thing to look at would be how the `TextView` is being populated. Maybe the actual data is being lost somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use Instance variables to store data inside each Fragment, if you are using replace E.g.:

```
String value = "";
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.setText(value);

}
```

Note: Update value variable as well whenever textview data is being updated.